# Where is the mistake in my algebraic proof?

Tags: proof-verification, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and consider the ring $A:=k[X,Y]/(Y^2-X^2(X-1))$, which is of course a domain. We have that the localization of $A$ at $X$, i.e. $A[1/X]$ is given by $k[X,Y,1/X]/(Y^2-X^2(X-1))$, therefore the subring $A[Y/X]$ of $A[1/X]$ is given by $k[X,Y/X]/(Y^2-X^2(X-1))$. I would prove that the ideal $(Y^2-X^2(X-1))$ of $A[Y/X]$ is $((Y/X)^2-(X-1))$. Now, we have $\mathfrak{p}=(Y^2-X^2(X-1))=(X^2)\cdot((Y/X)^2-(X-1))=\mathfrak{p}_1\cdot\mathfrak{p}_2$ in $k[X,Y/X]$, therefore since $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime in $k[X,Y/X]$, we have that $\mathfrak{p}$ must contain at least one of $\mathfrak{p}_i$'s. Now, it's simple to check that $\mathfrak{p}$ does not contain $\mathfrak{p}_1$, therefore $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{p}_2$. My problem is the following...

**P.** By what I showed, $X^2$ must be a unit in $k[X,Y/X]$, then $X\in k[X,Y/X]$ is a unit, but this is of course false. Where is the mistake in the proof I done above?

Comment: I don't understand how did you conclude that $\mathfrak p=((Y/X)^2-(X-1))$ is prime in $K[X,Y/X]$. This is prime in $R=K[X,Y]$, but $S=K[X,Y/X]=R[Y/X]$ is an extension of $R$, $Y/X$ is not integral over $R$ (but it's algebraic!), so I can't see much hope to get that $\mathfrak pS$ is prime. Moreover, after claiming that $\mathfrak pS$ is prime you proved exactly the contrary since $X^2((Y/X)^2-(X-1))\in\mathfrak pS$ and $X^2\notin\mathfrak pS$ and $(Y/X)^2-(X-1)\notin\mathfrak pS$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's incorrect to say $A[Y/X]=k[X,Y/X]/(Y^2-X^2(X-1))$.  What you know is that $A[Y/X]$ is the subring of $k[X,Y,1/X]/(Y^2-X^2(X-1))$ generated by $X$ and $Y/X$, so it is $k[X,Y/X]/I$ where $I=k[X,Y/X]\cap J$ where $J$ is the ideal generated by $Y^2-X^2(X-1)$ in $k[X,Y,1/X]$.  But this ideal $I$ is not necessarily generated by $Y^2-X^2(X-1)$ in $k[X,Y/X]$.  Indeed, $(Y/X)^2-(X-1)\in I$ but $(Y/X)^2-(X-1)$ is not in the ideal of $k[X,Y/X]$ generated by $Y^2-X^2(X-1)$.

More generally, what's going on here is that if $B$ is a subring of $C$ and $J$ is an ideal of $C$ generated by elements of $B$, then $J\cap B$ need not be generated by those same elements of $B$.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful remark!